# Human-powered lawnmower with horizontal blade?

Tags: lawn-mower

I really like my "old-fashioned" reel mower.  It does a pretty good job, and I like getting more exercise.  Not buying gasoline is also nice.

But, it is slightly less efficient at getting taller plants, as they just lay down in front of it and pop back up behind it.

Is there such a thing as a horizontal blade driven from the wheels?  And if so, how do I find one?  (Or what is it called so I can do a web search?)

Comment: It is called a scythe and does not need wheels - good for upper body exercise though.

Comment: This isn't a home improvement question. You might try https://gardening.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I just accept that some lanky weeds will not get cut by my manual reel mower.

Comment: So do I, but if I could find a way to prevent it …

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on a gardening-related board.

Answer (score 3):

Driven by wheels - **No.** People powered horizontal blade for taller plants, **Yes indeed.**

Ignoring the request for wheels, what you want is a scythe.

[image: Scythe picture from scythe supply no endorsement implied]

Having used both, I'm fond of the "European" pattern (nearly straight-snath) type rather than the heavy, very curvy "American" pattern

Owning both, I find my scythe a heck of a lot nicer to use than my big gas string trimmer. I can cut at a similar rate of speed, in quiet, and not end up covered in green goo from head to toe. It's rather like a relaxing martial art or dance.

You will need more than just a scythe, to use a scythe effectively you also need a kit to peen (hammer-shape) the blade and a stone to sharpen it - a scythe does not work well at all when dull, but it's no more hassle really than keeping string trimmer string loaded and feeding correctly.

Comment: I might get one just to see the look of the neighbors walking by as I’m trimming the grass overhanging the sidewalk.

Comment: @statueuphemism be careful - you could take their head off...

Comment: @SolarMike I was thinking of angling more for the ankles personally. ;-)

Comment: Cue the Black Knight scene from *Search for the Holy Grail*

Comment: Well, a scythe is a possibility, but I was hoping for rotary, with a height that does depend on my skill to maintain consistency.  (And, I actually have a string trimmer that feeds itself somehow.  Others feed when tapped on the ground.)

Comment: You have a reel mower, so once you knock down the taller growth you can trim it to accurate height with that. If your string trimmer has never jammed, you are very lucky, or you don't use it much. If you don't mind the mess, the string trimmer can do that for you, of course. Then just reel often enough that nothing gets too tall, or pull out the trimmer if it does.

Comment: The only drawback to the scythe is that it takes significant skill to use it right up against a fence, foundation, tree, or post without damaging something (or someone).

Answer (score 1):

Push lawnmowers come form an age where things weren't motorized. They cut the grass with a 'scissor' action giving a nice, clean cut (when they're sharp), which means the blades don't have to travel terribly fast to do their job.

Modern spinning-horizontal-blade mowers are simply much cheaper to manufacture and maintain. They operate by spinning at such a high speed that they simply tear the grass in two when they hit it. It wouldn't be possible (I think) to gear it such that you could get the blade spinning fast enough to actually cut the grass, without the wheel slipping (and it being very hard to push).

So, no, I don't think what you want exists.

Comment: The reel mower spins fast enough with wheels.  I did consider the slipping problem, but I think if it had something like caterpillar treads …

Comment: @WGroleau It would be too much to push, though.  Look at gas reel mowers, they are in the 3hp range, and that's really because they don't make 0.5HP engines.  Look at gas spinning-blade mowers, 6-7hp per blade.

Comment: I don't understand why the same push on the same wheels can cut grass with one geometry and not with another.  I guess it's because the rotary requires much more speed, since it doesn't have the stationary blade to scissor with.  Hmmm.

Comment: @WGroleau - Yes. Exactly that. It's an entirely different (much less efficient, but cheap) cutting action.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a tool that's gonna do it all in one shot.  That's not gonna happen. Cutting tall grass, especially with a rotary blade, takes *far* more power than you can generate via wheels/transmission on a push mower.

Really, that rotary push mower is a "finish mower" - it's designed to groom a lawn that is already in control.

You need to use other tools to get the lawn in control, first.

What I've always used is - gosh, it's hard to name it, but a "[weed cutter](https://www.true-temper.com/tool/lawn-garden-tools/2945000-deluxe-weed-cutter/)", "swing grass cutter", "grass shear" or "swing cutter" or "s**w**ing blade".

[image]

It's vaguely like a scythe but double-faced, so you can be productive on both swings.  They're crazy productive - once you use one, you won't be able to believe anyone uses string trimmers in open areas.  Obviously it does take ...skill... 
[and this person sure doesn't have it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oc57K6m-FtU)... but once you get dialed in, it makes short work of the high stuff.

Then you bring in your finish mower.

If this doesn't appeal because you don't want to have to use it every 2 weeks, then the root problem is you don't mow often enough.  Power mowers will let you get away with murder: you can cut stuff 2 feet high with power mowers.  Not with a push mower.  You have to be "on it", and pay attention to things that affect grass growth, like rain.

Comment: I never said the lawn is out of control and I never mentioned tall grass.  And I don't wait two weeks between mowings.  I may get another one of those items you picture.  Used to have one.  The gas mower handles everything in one shot.  The one I prefer handles everything except the occasional weed that shoots up fifteen centimeters in two days.